# Coffee percolator

Tags: brewing-process, flavor, moka

I have bought an Italian percolator and cannot get the taste right, like you would find in a coffee house.

[image: Percolator]

I buy beans from a proper coffee house and tried many different coffee types and origins.

The taste I am trying to achieve is basically the French coffee taste you get in brasseries.

The owner of the coffee place I buy from heavily roasts my beans but I still can’t get it right. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And - second clarification question - you want the kind of coffee you would get at a brasserie in France? (Which iirc is quite different from an espresso?)

Comment: @Stephie the type of coffee you find in France as well as an espresso. Both

Comment: A correction first; this is not a percolator ([see](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/418/whats-the-difference-between-a-percolator-and-a-moka-pot)). [tag:moka] tag in general may help. Following are recent discussions on how to prepare coffee with a moka pot: [one](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/why-does-my-moka-pot-sometimes-produce-great-coffee-and-sometimes-awful-coffee), [two](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/improving-my-brikka-moka-pot-use), [three](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/how-do-i-make-an-espresso-shot-in-a-moka-pot).